# How to generate examples for fluid mechanics?

Tags: education, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

I've noticed a serious lack of examples for students learning fluid mechanics, and I started trying to come up with examples.  In the case of incompressible fluids (constant density) the only thing required is a velocity field, and that comes from a velocity potential.

But what about compressible fluids?  Is there any straightforward way to generate a density function to be compatible (in terms of satisfying the continuity equation) with a given velocity field?  For that matter, can any vector field be a velocity field if you use an appropriate density function?  Are the conservation equations themselves the only constraints on a model/example for fluid flow?

Comment: In Majda & Bertozzi's book (chapter 1), there are some explicit examples for incompressible flow in some detail. I don't know about compressible